# Street Fighter selection with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

i want to make a history of selections in a two dimensional array.
What i got is this:

```
var fighters = [
["Ryu", "E.Honda", "Blanka", "Guile", "Balrog", "Vega"],
["Ken", "Chun Li", "Zangief", "Dhalsim", "Sagat", "M.Bison"]
];

var initial_position = (0,0)
var moves = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'right']
```

What i want as a result is e.g.:

```
['E.Honda', 'Chun Li', 'Ken', 'M.Bison', 'Sagat', 'Dhalsim', 'Sagat']
```

the position [0,0] is in the top corner.
My problem is to decide whether the selection goes of the first Row that means the selected fighter would be the first one in the row. But the selection must not go over top oder under bottom row!

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Aside: `(0,0)` is just `0`. Javascript doesn't have tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if some element in `initial_position` is less then 0 or bigger then maximum which is `fighters.length` or `fighters[0].length` and reset it to that maximum number.

```js
var fighters = [
  ["Ryu", "E.Honda", "Blanka", "Guile", "Balrog", "Vega"],
  ["Ken", "Chun Li", "Zangief", "Dhalsim", "Sagat", "M.Bison"]
];

var moves = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'right']

var result = []
var ipos = [0, 0];
moves.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e == 'right') {
    ipos[0] += 1
  } else if (e == 'left') {
    ipos[0] -= 1
  } else if (e == 'down') {
    ipos[1] += 1;
  } else if (e == 'up') {
    ipos[1] -= 1
  }
  if (ipos[0] > fighters[0].length - 1 || ipos[0] < 0) ipos[0] = fighters[0].length - 1;
  if (ipos[1] > fighters.length - 1 || ipos[1] < 0) ipos[1] = fighters.length - 1;

  result.push(fighters[ipos[1]][ipos[0]])
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I had a mistake at `fighters.length - 1;` but now its fixed so if you go `down` more then you can it will stay and maximum rows but you can also change that and reset it to 0

Answer (score 0):

Cool..! I hate `if`s and `else`s... So let's get some functional and make a simple navigation system with our invention `Array.prototype.rotate()` in order to have the target cell at `fighters[0][0]` position all the time.

```js
Array.prototype.rotate = function(n) {
                           var len = this.length;
                           return !(n % len) ? this.slice()
                                             : this.map((e,i,a) => a[(i + (len + n % len)) % len]);
                         };

function navigate(m,f){
  var d = { left: a => a.map(e => e.rotate(-1)),
           right: a => a.map(e => e.rotate(1)),
              up: a => a.rotate(-1),
            down: a => a.rotate(1)
          };
  return m.reduce((p,c) => (f = d[c](f), p.concat(f[0][0])) ,[]);
}

var fighters = [["Ryu", "E.Honda", "Blanka", "Guile", "Balrog", "Vega"],
                ["Ken", "Chun Li", "Zangief", "Dhalsim", "Sagat", "M.Bison"]
               ],
       moves = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'right'];
console.log(navigate(moves,fighters));
```

This is quite fine but instead of rotating the array in order to keep the target cell at [0][0] position at all times, one could simply keep a cursor object and modify the `d` object to harbor the methods adjusting the cursor position according to the received commands. Then we only need an additional cursor object like `{x: 0, y: 0}`. Let me try to implement that one too in which we will no longer require the `Array.prototype.rotate()` thingy.

```js
function navigate(m,f){
  var c = {x: 0, y: 0},
      d = { left: c => (c.x = (c.x + f[c.y].length - 1 % f[c.y].length) % f[c.y].length,c),
           right: c => (c.x = (c.x + f[c.y].length + 1 % f[c.y].length) % f[c.y].length,c),
              up: c => (c.y = (c.y + f.length - 1 % f.length) % f.length,c),
            down: c => (c.y = (c.y + f.length + 1 % f.length) % f.length,c)
          };
  return m.reduce((p,n) => (d[n](c),p.concat(f[c.y][c.x])),[]);
}

var fighters = [["Ryu", "E.Honda", "Blanka", "Guile", "Balrog", "Vega"],
                ["Ken", "Chun Li", "Zangief", "Dhalsim", "Sagat", "M.Bison"]
               ],
       moves = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'right'];
console.log(navigate(moves,fighters));
```